# getting a conversion data from two tables

Tags: mysql, jsp, resultset

i have created two tables in mysql named as user and messages

user contains username,imgname,email,password
messages contains fromname,toname,message,msgdate,msgtime

all the fromname,toname fields are of username in user table
fromname and toname fields are foriengnkeys for username field in user table

I want a query in mysql which gives a specific set of records like if "abc" and "xyz" are two usernames i want to get records of imgname,message of their conversation

Comment: User name is one key while fromname an toname are two freign keys, how?

Answer (score 0):

You can get your desired result with this SQL:

```
Select username, message, msgdate, msgtime
from   users, messages
where  username = fromname
```